# How do I disable log messages from the Requests library?

Tags: python, logging, python-requests, python-logging, verbosity

By default, the [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) python library writes log messages to the console, along the lines of:

```
Starting new HTTP connection (1): example.com
http://example.com:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 606
```

I'm usually not interested in these messages, and would like to disable them. What would be the best way to silence those messages or decrease Requests' verbosity?

Comment: Related: [nginx and gunicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48700404/562769)

Answer (score 719, accepted):

I found out how to configure *requests*'s logging level, it's done via the standard [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module. I decided to configure it to not log messages unless they are at least warnings:

```
import logging

logging.getLogger("requests").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

If you wish to apply this setting for the urllib3 library (typically used by requests) too, add the following:

```
logging.getLogger("urllib3").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Comment: I have same issue with `pysimplesoap`, and this answer help me save my day

Comment: You could combine the two lines like this:
logging.getLogger('requests').setLevel(logging.WARNING)

Comment: @JasperPoppe Thanks for the suggestion, implemented.

Comment: I had to add this line for the "urllib3" logger to suppress requests log messages.

Comment: I was need to import logging; logging.getLogger("urllib3").setLevel(logging.WARNING), too. Logger for "requests" doesn't prevent these messages.

Comment: For some reason when using the requests library in python3 you have to do `getLogger("urllib3")` to suppress the messages.

Comment: @Robru Sounds as if requests is basing itself on urllib3 these days quite simply, which does logging of its own. That's how it goes :)

Comment: Is there a way to make change the level of the logging from requests to DEBUG instead of INFO? I would like to keep the messages, but only at the DEBUG level (so they are only in my offline debug log, and not on the screen).

Comment: @FrankMeulenaar I would pose that as an independent question. Anyhow, I guess what I would do is configure the requests stream handler outputting to screen to ignore anything below or equal to INFO.

Comment: I set it to `CRITICAL` but I'm still getting the same log message: `2017-08-05 15:17:13,334 ERROR -- : Certificate did not match expected hostname: www.improving-autonomy.org. Certificate: {'subjectAltName': [('DNS', '*.wordpress.com'), ('DNS', 'wordpress.com')], 'subject': ((('commonName', u'*.wordpress.com'),),)}` Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Solved. Full path was needed: `logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3").setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)`

Comment: Current versions of the `requests` library do not vendor `urllib3` any more and so doesn't log *anything*. You only need to ask the `urllib3` library to not propagate: `logging.getLogger("urllib3").propagate = False`, or increase the logging level if you still need to see warnings or critical messages (only warnings are issued currently).

Answer (score 139):

In case you came here looking for a way to modify logging of any (possibly deeply nested) module, use `logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict` to get a dictionary of all of the logger objects. The returned names can then be used as the argument to `logging.getLogger`:

```
import requests
import logging
for key in logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict:
    print(key)
# requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool
# requests.packages.urllib3.util
# requests.packages
# requests.packages.urllib3
# requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry
# PYREADLINE
# requests
# requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager

logging.getLogger('requests').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
# Could also use the dictionary directly:
# logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict['requests'].setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

Per user136036 in a comment, be aware that this method only shows you the loggers that exist at the time you run the above snippet. If, for example, a module creates a new logger when you instantiate a class, then you must put this snippet *after* creating the class in order to print its name.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me silence `urllib3` log messages when using `boto3`. The logger in such case is `botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3`, so I used this: `logging.getLogger("botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3").setLevel(logging.WARNING)` and I finally got rid of the messages.

Comment: Many thanks for this! Altering the print criteria allowed me to isolate that python-elasticsearch was the culprit in my case.

Comment: Be aware that this will not work when modules create their loggers inside their class you'd call later, like the `APScheduler` does when you call `BackgroundScheduler.BackgroundScheduler()`.

Comment: @user136036: logger objects are singletons, it doesn't matter if you or the library get to create them first. If you use the exact same name as the library uses, *it will work*.

Comment: I think they are saying that if you list the loggers before a library has created its logger, then it won’t be listed. Which is correct.

Comment: This helped me find the module that was writing log messages with request information that I wanted to get rid off (`azure`). Thank you so much!

Comment: This is a lifesaver. I was trying to disable logging by setting `propagate = False` and could not get it working no matter what. Finally, this helped me to get logger name as `urllib3.connectionpool` as `urllib3` and `connectionpool` would not work.

Answer (score 32):

```
import logging
urllib3_logger = logging.getLogger('urllib3')
urllib3_logger.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

In this way all the messages of level=INFO from urllib3 won't be present in the logfile.

So you can continue to use the level=INFO for your log messages...just modify this for the library you are using.

Comment: I suggest using `setLevel(logging.WARNING)` to log also possible warning and error messages.

Answer (score 30):

```
import logging

# Only show warnings
logging.getLogger("urllib3").setLevel(logging.WARNING)

# Disable all child loggers of urllib3, e.g. urllib3.connectionpool
logging.getLogger("urllib3").propagate = False
```

Answer (score 20):

For anybody using `logging.config.dictConfig` you can alter the requests library log level in the dictionary like this:

```
'loggers': {
    '': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': level,
        'propagate': False
    },
    'requests.packages.urllib3': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': logging.WARNING
    }
}
```

Comment: @SebastianWagner Django uses `dictConfig` under the hood.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is pretty good. One place to rule all of the library logs!! :)

Answer (score 15):

Let me copy/paste the documentation section which it I wrote about week or two ago, after having a problem similar to yours:

```
import requests
import logging

# these two lines enable debugging at httplib level (requests->urllib3->httplib)
# you will see the REQUEST, including HEADERS and DATA, and RESPONSE with HEADERS but without DATA.
# the only thing missing will be the response.body which is not logged.
import httplib
httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

logging.basicConfig() # you need to initialize logging, otherwise you will not see anything from requests
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True

requests.get('http://httpbin.org/headers')
```

Comment: What's the point of being more specific than just 'requests' though, from a practical POV?

Comment: But what do you gain by calling logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3") instead of logging.getLogger("requests"), considering that you want to affect the logging of the requests library?

Comment: Do you mean that you wish to enable logging within requests.packages.urllib3? If so, you're answering the wrong question.

Comment: @aknuds1 It's up to you if you want to disable or enable them, I only put the code that fully controls this :)

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question's scope.

Answer (score 8):

Setting the logger name as `requests` or `requests.urllib3` did not work for me. I had to specify the exact logger name to change the logging level.

First See which loggers you have defined, to see which ones you want to remove

```
print(logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict)
```

And you will see something like this:

`{...'urllib3.poolmanager': <logging.Logger object at 0x1070a6e10>, 'django.request': <logging.Logger object at 0x106d61290>, 'django.template': <logging.Logger object at 0x10630dcd0>, 'django.server': <logging.Logger object at 0x106dd6a50>, 'urllib3.connection': <logging.Logger object at 0x10710a350>,'urllib3.connectionpool': <logging.Logger object at 0x106e09690> ...}`

Then configure the level for the exact logger:

```
   'loggers': {
    '': {
        'handlers': ['default'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True
    },
    'urllib3.connectionpool': {
        'handlers': ['default'],
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'propagate' : False
    },
```

Comment: where are these levels set?

Comment: I have them in Django settings, in base.py. Where to put them of course depends on your project setup.

Answer (score 6):

If You have configuration file, You can configure it.

Add urllib3 in loggers section:

```
[loggers]
keys = root, urllib3
```

Add logger_urllib3 section:

```
[logger_urllib3]
level = WARNING
handlers =
qualname = requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool
```

Comment: This is a perfectly valid answer for people who use configuration file. Not sure why it got so many down vote?

Answer (score 4):

This answer is here:  [Python: how to suppress logging statements from third party libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944445/python-how-to-suppress-logging-statements-from-third-party-libraries)

You can leave the default logging level for basicConfig, and then you set the DEBUG level when you get the logger for your module.

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(module)s %(filename)s:%(lineno)s - %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logger.debug("my debug message")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the previous approaches have stopped working, but in any case, here's another way of removing the warnings:

```
PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore:Unverified HTTPS request" ./do-insecure-request.py
```

Basically, adding an environment variable in the context of the script execution.

From the documentation: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#disabling-warnings

Answer (score 0):

Kbrose's guidance on finding which logger was generating log messages was immensely useful. For my Django project, I had to sort through 120 different loggers until I found that it was the `elasticsearch` Python library that was causing issues for me. As per the guidance in most of the questions, I disabled it by adding this to my loggers:

```
      ...
      'elasticsearch': {
          'handlers': ['console'],
          'level': logging.WARNING,
      },     
      ...
```

Posting here in case someone else is seeing the unhelpful log messages come through whenever they run an Elasticsearch query.

Answer (score 0):

In my case what helped me (python 3.7)

```
import http.client as http_client
http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 0
```

Answer (score -1):

simple: just add `requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()` after `import requests`

Comment: I did not find this method in my version.  Disabling warnings is excessive, as the annoying messages are level `INFO`.