# How can I see the actual data Requests sends over the wire?

Tags: python, oauth, python-requests, urllib3, rauth

(This is a follow-up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337511/log-all-requests-from-the-python-requests-module))

How can I tell `urllib3` to log the **FULL** request, including, but not limited to:

- URL
- query parameters
- headers
- body
- *and* anything else which is sent inside the request (I am not sure there is anything else, but if there is something else, I also want to see it)

I am having trouble connecting to LinkedIn with OAuth (a similar implementation works with Google and Facebook), and I would like to see **exactly** what requests are being sent. I suspect the `auth_token` is not being provided, but I need to confirm this. For that, I need `urllib3` to show the full requests, since they are over HTTPS and I can not analyze network traffic to see them (end-to-end encryption).

Comment: You should spend some time exploring the Requests API; I'm noticing a lot of your questions you could answer yourself if you read the rauth and Requests documentation. For example, access to the `PreparedRequest` object from the `Response` object is fully discussed in Requests' documentation.

Comment: Sure you are right. If I had the time to read the documentation of Requests, urrlib3 and rauth (and any other dependency), remember all those details, and apply them to my particular case, deciding how to solve my specific problem, I would have solved this isssue myself. Heck, I would never need Stackoverflow!  I am not even interested in the requests content: I was just trying to get OAuth2 working with linkedin, which is, strangely enough, expecting oauth2_access_token instead of access_token, the default in rauth (which can not be overridden), and wants no bearer token in the header.

Comment: And just to clarify. The way I see it, you are the expert in your library. I am not. I - and others - need your help (which you can give or not) I assume you need the help from others regarding other issues, and that you are not expert in all areas. So often you will ask stupid or obvious questions. At least I do. So yes, you can complain that I am asking stupid questions (this is not the silliest question that I have asked), but I already knew that. Somewhere, someplace is the answer to my question. I just do not know where, and this is (for me) the right place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `PreparedRequest` object that was actually sent after the fact of a request by using the `request` accessor, e.g. `print dir(r.request)`.

Comment: This requires access to the response themselves, which I believe the OP doesn't have.

Comment: If he's using rauth, he absolutely does.

Comment: I'll just take your word for that, I don't use the library myself.

Comment: You can take my word for it, I'm the author.

Comment: Right, that would give you a certain, shall we say, advantage!

Answer (score 0):

You can hack into the [`requests` hooks system](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced.html#event-hooks) instead, then use that to track responses and their requests:

```
from requests import hooks


_orig_default_hooks = hooks.default_hooks


def my_default_hooks():
    hooks = _orig_default_hooks()
    hooks['response'].append(response_hook)
    return hooks


hooks.default_hooks = my_default_hooks


# requests.models is imported by the requests package, so we need to ensure it's reference
# to default_hooks is updated too.
import requests.models
requests.models.default_hooks = my_default_hooks


def response_hook(r, **kw):
    req = r.request
    print req.headers
```

The `reqeuests.hooks.default_hooks()` function is called for each and every request created, and by injecting your own `response` event hook you get to see each and every response received. Responses have a `.request` attribute, which is a `PreparedRequest` instance, on which you'll find the `.headers` and `.body` attributes for your inspection.

Comment: That looks interesting. I'll have a look.

Comment: And just for info, I also found this discussion on the urrlib3 issue tracker: https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/107. Not yet sure what to make of that.

Comment: @gonvaled: ah, `httplib` is Python 2, renamed to `http.client` in Python 3 of course.