# Python GET Requests causing 100% CPU Usage Spike

Tags: python, http, get, python-requests

I'm using the python requests library (version 2.4.1) for performing a simple get request, code is below, nothing fancy here. On most website's there are no issues. But on some websites, one in particular www.pricegrabber.com, I experience 100% CPU usage and the code never moves past the point of the get request. No timeout occurs, nothing, just a huge CPU usage spike that never stops.

```
import requests
url = 'http://www.pricegrabber.com'
r = requests.get(url, timeout=(1, 1))
print 'SUCESS'
print r
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using python 2.7, the latest stable version of the 'requests' library, and enabling logging as [shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337511/log-all-requests-from-the-python-requests-module) indicates that the HTTP request is stuck in a redirect loop.

> INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): www.pricegrabber.com
>   DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 20
>   DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /index.php/ut=43bb2597a77557f5 HTTP/1.1" 301 20
>   DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /?ut=43bb2597a77557f5 HTTP/1.1" 301 20
>   DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /?ut=43bb2597a77557f5 HTTP/1.1" 301 20
>   DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /?ut=43bb2597a77557f5 HTTP/1.1" 301 20
>
> ...

This continues a bit until:

> requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.

And the code I used to discover this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import logging
import requests

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

url = 'http://www.pricegrabber.com'
r = requests.get(url, timeout=(1, 1))

print 'SUCCESS'
print r
```

Comment: I don't get that exception. I only get 3 redirects and it gets stuck on DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /?ut=324aba6b1a542668 HTTP/1.1" 301 20

Comment: Your experience may vary based on what the website returns to you. Can you find out what version of 'requests' you're using?

Comment: requests 2.4.1. I'm going to upgrade maybe there was a patch for this issue.

Comment: That fixed it! It looks like there was an issue with version 2.4.1 I updated to 2.5.0 and I get a toomanyredirects

Comment: @digitaldavenyc yeah, that was a problem in 2.4.1. 2.4.2 had a release bug (problem with the release, not the code) but it was fixed properly in 2.4.3