# Escaping backslash in Python requests arguments

Tags: python, api, request

I'm trying to implement ZULU TRADE's REST API on Python, by using "requests".

The problem is that trading pairs have a slash in the middle of it ('EUR/USD').
So when I send a request to open a market order a get this:
http://tradingserver.zulutrade.com/open/market/?lots=0.01&requestedPrice=1.5&buy=True&currencyName=EUR%2FUSD&uniqueId=75479982

instead of this:
http://tradingserver.zulutrade.com/open/market/?currencyName=EUR/USD&lots=0.01&buy=true&requestedPrice=1.4&uniqueId=1430761124723

The slash is converted to %2F. Is there a way to prevent this?

Thank you
HUPP

Comment: Rather than linking to the code samples, it is best to include the samples in your post. The reason is that links are not reliable. They expire or -- as is the case for the links provided -- may require request headers that are not present in the request. Please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That's correct though.  The slash should be url encoded.

Comment: Could it have something to do with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315914/escaping-backslash-in-python-requests