# Python requests gets an error page for a URL that should work fine

Tags: python, http, curl, python-requests

I'm trying to use a python script to scrape a handful of pages on a government website. I have it accessing [a URL](http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/ResultsByNameServlet?bizname=a&licensetype=C) that loads a normal webpage in my web browser, but for some reason the script gets an "Access Denied" page instead of the expected page.

Additionally, this "Access Denied" error is unlike any I have ever seen on the government website; I can't achieve this error through any means *but* my python script.

Here is a stripped down version of my script (it's rather big, so I cut out bits I don't think are relevant):

```python
import requests

headers = {
    'Accept': "*/*",
    'User-Agent': "nyc_contractors.py",
    'X-Love': "hey sysadmin! you're awesome! <3"
}

print "and we're off!"

qLicensetype="C"
qBizname = "a"

baseUrl = "http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/ResultsByNameServlet?bizname="+qBizname+"&licensetype="+qLicensetype
nextUrl = baseUrl

while nextUrl != None:

    print
    print "URL:", nextUrl

    r = requests.get(nextUrl, headers=headers)
    nextUrl = None # kill the url (if there's a next page, we'll restore the url later)
    print "actual url:",r.url

    lines = r.text.splitlines()

    for line in lines:
        print "L:", line
```

And here is the log output from running that script:

```
and we're off!

URL: http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/ResultsByNameServlet?bizname=a&licensetype=C
actual url: http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/ResultsByNameServlet?bizname=a&licensetype=C
L: <HTML><HEAD>
L: <TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
L: </HEAD><BODY>
L: <H1>Access Denied</H1>
L:  
L: You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;a810&#45;bisweb&#46;nyc&#46;gov&#47;bisweb&#47;ResultsByNameServlet&#63;" on this server.<P>
L: Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;85600317&#46;1438181595&#46;a09a236f
L: </BODY>
L: </HTML>
```

For sake of readability, here's what that error page basically looks like:

> **Access Denied**
>
> You don't have permission to access "http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/ResultsByNameServlet?" on this server.
>
> Reference #18.85600317.1438181008.a0891486

Some things to note:

- This same machine is simultaneously running a different script that's also using requests to download pages from a different website. That couldn't interfere... could it?
- I thought maybe this website is blocking me because it doesn't like my user agent or something, so I tried accessing the URL via cURL, and it worked just as well as in my browser.

Does anyone have any idea what the issue might be? Many thanks.

EDIT: Something I forgot to mention. I noticed it was going through multiple requests way faster than seemed feasible, so I thought maybe it was somehow connected to the web server running on the local machine, but I didn't see any requests that looked like they could be the source in my local server's access logs.

EDIT: @Alik suggested I rerun my local script with logging enabled, so here's that output:

```
URL: http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/ResultsByNameServlet?bizname=s&licensetype=B
INFO:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): a810-bisweb.nyc.gov
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /bisweb/ResultsByNameServlet?bizname=s&licensetype=B HTTP/1.1" 403 309
actual url: http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/ResultsByNameServlet?bizname=s&licensetype=B
L: <HTML><HEAD>
L: <TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
L: </HEAD><BODY>
L: <H1>Access Denied</H1>
L:  
L: You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;a810&#45;bisweb&#46;nyc&#46;gov&#47;bisweb&#47;ResultsByNameServlet&#63;" on this server.<P>
L: Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;85600317&#46;1438184686&#46;a0f4b341
L: </BODY>
L: </HTML>
```

Comment: When you test with cURL, are you accessing several URLs in a tight loop or just one? In other words, are you ruling out the case that they're actually blocking based on the frequency of the requests?

Comment: I don't think it's a frequency thing, because even the very first request gets this error.

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem, the script works fine for me.

Comment: Really? That's very strange, what could be different in my environment... EDIT: Hmm, looks like my stripped down script doesn't have the error (mea culpa for not testing it before posting)

Comment: @oxguy3 enable logging and run your script again http://stackoverflow.com/a/16337639/471899

Answer (score 3):

Okay this is the stupidest problem and I literally don't understand why it would happen, but I solved it. Anyway, the script in my post works because I accidentally changed my User-Agent there to "nyc_contractors.py". The script fails on my end because, in the actual version I was running, I had "nyc_contractor_scraper.py", and for some reason it doesn't like that specific user agent (maybe it blacklists "scraper"? who knows)

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this same thing. The problem turned out to be that the website was blocking the python-requests User Agent.

You can check what your user agent is by enabling debugging at the `httplib` level as [explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24588289/2981358) by @Yohann.

You change the user agent used by `requests` as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10606260/2981358) by @birryree.

Changing the user agent to one which isn't blocked should fix the problem if that's what's happening to you as well.