# Python requests view before sending

Tags: python, python-requests

Can somebody please provide me with a way to see a request that I have generated before sending it to a server, here is the code:

```
import requests
import urllib2
import logging

from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

url = "https://10.1.1.254:4081/admin/api/jsonrpc/"
session = requests.Session()

data = {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "Session.login",
    "params": {"userName": "test", "password":"test123"}
}
r = session.post(url, json=data, verify=False)

data = {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id":3, "method":"Session.logout"}
r = session.post(url, json=data, verify=False)
```

So what I would like is to get that request sent with session.post, before Python sends it.

Comment: Check http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#prepared-requests, I am not sure what you want check as part of the request , but you can access the members of request being sent with Requests object or prepared requests object.

Comment: I would like to see what the request compiled by "session.post(url, json=data, verify=False)" looks like before sending?

Answer (score 32):

You have three options here:

- by using a prepared request,
- inspecting the request *after it has been sent*,
- you can enable logging in `urllib3` as well as enable debugging in the `http.client` library.

They give you different levels of control over what is output.

### Prepared requests

You can [*prepare* a request](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#prepared-requests), which gives you a new object with all the data set up in final form. You can look at the [`requests.PreparedRequest` API docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.PreparedRequest) for the full list of attributes.

Here is a sample function that simply formats that data as if it were sent over the network (except it doesn't actually use CRLF line separators, and replacing binary content with a placeholder string):

```
def format_prepped_request(prepped, encoding=None):
    # prepped has .method, .path_url, .headers and .body attribute to view the request
    encoding = encoding or requests.utils.get_encoding_from_headers(prepped.headers)
    body = prepped.body.decode(encoding) if encoding else '<binary data>' 
    headers = '\n'.join(['{}: {}'.format(*hv) for hv in prepped.headers.items()])
    return f"""\
{prepped.method} {prepped.path_url} HTTP/1.1
{headers}

{body}"""
```

Use a prepareded request *instead* of using `session.[httpmethod]()`, and instead use [`session.send()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Session.send) to send out the prepared request after you've inspected it. Put the HTTP method as the first argument of `Request()` instead (uppercased). So `session.post(...)` becomes `Request('POST', ...)`. All other arguments, *except for `verify`* are moved to the `Request()` call:

```
url = "https://10.1.1.254:4081/admin/api/jsonrpc/"
session = requests.Session()

data = {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0", "id":1, "method": "Session.login",
    "params": {"userName": "test", "password":"test123"}
}

request = requests.Request('POST', url, json=data)
prepped = session.prepare_request(request)

print("Sending request:")
print(format_prepped_request(prepped, 'utf8'))
print()
r = session.send(prepped, verify=False)

data = {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id":3, "method":"Session.logout"}
request = requests.Request('POST', url, json=data)
prepped = session.prepare_request(request)

print("Sending request:")
print(format_prepped_request(prepped, 'utf8'))
print()
r = session.send(prepped, verify=False)
```

For your sample requests, this outputs:

```
Sending request:
POST /admin/api/jsonrpc/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: python-requests/2.22.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 109
Content-Type: application/json

{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "Session.login", "params": {"userName": "test", "password": "test123"}}

Sending request:
POST /admin/api/jsonrpc/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: python-requests/2.22.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 55
Content-Type: application/json

{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 3, "method": "Session.logout"}
```

### Inspecting the request after sending

The response object references the prepared request object used to make the request, so you can print this *after* sending the request:

```
# ...
r = session.post(url, json=data, verify=False)
prepped = r.request
print("Request that was sent:")
print(format_prepped_request(prepped, 'utf8'))
print()
```

This isn't quite the same of course, the request has now already been sent. On the other hand, you don't need to use prepared requests directly, `session.post()` went through the steps to produce that object itself.

Do take into account that if your original request led to a redirect, that the final request may differ. Look at the [`response.history` attribute](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Response.history) to access any preceding responses (each with their own request attached).

### Logging

Using the [`logging` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html), as well as rigging up the `http.client.HTTPConnection` class to log its debug output to the same framework, you can get debug-level information on requests too. I'm using my answer to [Log all requests from the python-requests module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337511/log-all-requests-from-the-python-requests-module) here:

```
import logging

# function definition from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16337639/100297
# configures http.client to log rather than print
httpclient_logging_patch()
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

at which point you'll see requests appear in logging output:

```
DEBUG:http.client:send: b'POST /admin/api/jsonrpc/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 10.1.1.254:4081\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.22.0\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Length: 109\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n'
DEBUG:http.client:send: b'{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "Session.login", "params": {"userName": "test", "password": "test123"}}'
DEBUG:http.client:reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
DEBUG:http.client:header: Date: Tue, 04 Feb 2020 13:41:52 GMT
DEBUG:http.client:header: Content-Type: application/json
DEBUG:http.client:header: Content-Length: 574
DEBUG:http.client:header: Connection: keep-alive
DEBUG:http.client:header: Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
DEBUG:http.client:header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
DEBUG:http.client:header: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://10.1.1.254:4081 "POST /admin/api/jsonrpc/ HTTP/1.1" 200 574
DEBUG:http.client:send: b'POST /admin/api/jsonrpc/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 10.1.1.254:4081\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.22.0\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Length: 55\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n'
DEBUG:http.client:send: b'{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 3, "method": "Session.logout"}'
DEBUG:http.client:reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
DEBUG:http.client:header: Date: Tue, 04 Feb 2020 13:43:56 GMT
DEBUG:http.client:header: Content-Type: application/json
DEBUG:http.client:header: Content-Length: 574
DEBUG:http.client:header: Connection: keep-alive
DEBUG:http.client:header: Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
DEBUG:http.client:header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
DEBUG:http.client:header: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://10.1.1.254:4081 "POST /admin/api/jsonrpc/ HTTP/1.1" 200 574
```

This isn't as flexible as using prepared requests but would work with existing code-bases. It also outputs data for the *response*, but you can do the same with the response object that requests gives you and print that out like we did with prepared requests above.

Comment: I've been curious as to Why do we need to get prepared_request object when we can already control what headers, body, or any other information to send via a request/session object itself?

Answer (score 3):

What you want is to see how the original method `requests.post()` handles your input data and transforms it to the packets sent through the HTTP request.

If you look at the [post() source code](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/a9906536ee971872e5031a0138d63fb4ea481511/requests/sessions.py#L503) you can see that two objects are defined, `Request()` and then a `PreparedRequest()` (see [here](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/a9906536ee971872e5031a0138d63fb4ea481511/requests/sessions.py#L448)). These objects will provide you what you're looking for, and you can access them using method `prepare()`.

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23816211/6159698) that gives you the necessary code:

```
>>> import requests
>>> req = requests.Request('POST','http://stackoverflow.com',headers={'X-Custom':'Test'},data='a=1&b=2')
>>> prepared = req.prepare()
>>> print(prepared.body, prepared.headers)
a=1&b=2 {'X-Custom': 'Test', 'Content-Length': '7'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with the high-level helper functions. Instead you have to create a `request.PreparedRequest()` object. Usually you'd instantiate a `request.Request` object (which is a bit higher level), `prepare()` that to get a `PreparedRequest`, then you can `session.send(req)`.

Before sending, you can dump the various data from the PrepareRequest, I don't think there's a good builtin way to do that but for the most part the HTTP adapter will just write the request's `method`, `url`, `headers` and `body` to the connection it opened. So printing those before sending should be a good enough approximation, possibly with some formatting.

An alternative is to just configure httplib/urllib3/requests in debug (don't remember what it's called exactly) so that it automatically prints the request/response.

Answer (score 1):

For those who want to view the **RAW** request before sending:

If you just want a quick and dirty **(emphasis on the dirty)** way of seeing and manipulating the exact bytes being sent to and from the server, you can override the following methods:

```
from http.client import HTTPConnection, HTTPResponse, _MAXLINE

# Spy on request
oldsend = HTTPConnection.send
def newsend(self, data):
    print(data)
    oldsend(self, data)

HTTPConnection.send = newsend

# Spy on response
def newinit(self, sock, *args, **kwargs):
    # Increase timeout value if we are reading the socket too soon
    sock.settimeout(1.0)
    output = b""
    while True:
        try:
            output += sock.recv(4096)
        except:
            break        
    print(output)

HTTPResponse.__init__ = newinit

# Doing the request
import requests

requests.get("https://httpbin.org/get")
```

This generates the following output (tested on Python 3.10):

```
>>> requests.get("https://httpbin.org/get")
b'GET /get HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: httpbin.org\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.28.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n'
b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: Sun, 21 Aug 2022 17:34:56 GMT\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nContent-Length: 306\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nServer: gunicorn/19.9.0\r\nAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\nAccess-Control-Allow-Credentials: true\r\n\r\n{\n  "args": {}, \n  "headers": {\n    "Accept": "*/*", \n    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", \n    "Host": "httpbin.org", \n    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.28.1", \n    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-63026cc0-36c4e3020ecbfde82b5587e9"\n  }, \n  "origin": "84.105.13.27", \n  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get"\n}\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'fp'
```

This override only depends on the python standard library and will work with any library that uses `http.client` or `urllib3` under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "see a request".
Given that the return value of `session.post` is a `requests.Response`, check

```
print(dir(requests.Response))

['__attrs__', '__bool__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__eq__', '__exit__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'apparent_encoding', 'close', 'content', 'is_permanent_redirect', 'is_redirect', 'iter_content', 'iter_lines', 'json', 'links', 'next', 'ok', 'raise_for_status', 'text']
```

Perhaps what you are looking for is `content`, `json`, or `text`.
I am not certain.
So far I couldn't test it because I get

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] ...
```

in your line

```
r = session.post(url, data_json, verify=False)
```

(I am not sure if it is because of my poor connection here).