# Random Network problems with python under Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-requests, urllib

I'm using the requests module for url fetching under linux (minibian) via ethernet on a raspberry pi 1.

To fetch the data i use a loop over a list of urls:

```
for url in urllist:
   response = requests.get(url,timeout=5)
```

I get randomly the error: "[Errno 101] Network is unreachable requests".
Befor i tested the urrlib modul with "urllopen" and the same error.
The confusing is the script runs under Windows 10 without any error.

So is there a linux network configuration problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you get the errors randomly? My idea is that there's an url in that list that is blocked by a firewall on your linux machine.

Comment: How can i proof if a firewall is running? I disabled the ufw-firewall. I fetch from the same url, but different data ( yahoo finance api). Could there maybe be a problem with dns or something else?

Comment: This really sounds like some sort of basic networking problem.

Comment: maybe you can get some more insight by turning on logging, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337511/log-all-requests-from-the-python-requests-module  or http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.6/user/advanced/#verbose-logging