# Exact Online API returns null values

Tags: python, api, python-requests, exact-online

First off, I'm really new to the python requests module and using API in general. Chances are I made a basic mistake somewhere.

I'm trying to retrieve data from the exactonline API. Some data (eg: list of projects and cost transactions) I can retrieve relatively simply, so bearer code and current division should be ok. However, when I try to request data regarding hours worked I get only Null and 0 values.

I'm using requests as specified by this page: https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResources.aspx?SourceAction=10

To be specific, I've tried these 4 functions:

1. RecentHours
2. HoursByDate
3. HoursById
4. RecentHoursByNumberOfWeeks

For RecentHours I use

```
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + bearer_token}
    result = requests.get('https://start.exactonline.nl/api/v1/' + CURRENT_DIVISION + "/read/project/RecentHours",
                          headers=headers,
                          params=query_args)
    return(result.text)
```

For HoursByWeek I use (I currently only request one piece of information because that way I'm sure I didn't make any typo's in the query_args):

```
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + bearer_token}
    query_args = {'numberOfWeeks': '15',
                  'select': 'AccountCode'}
    result = requests.get('https://start.exactonline.nl/api/v1/' + CURRENT_DIVISION + "/read/project/RecentHoursByNumberOfWeeks",
                          headers=headers,
                          params=query_args)
    return(result.text)
```

All return status code 200, and no data.

According to this page (https://support.exactonline.com/community/s/knowledge-base?language=en_GB#All-All-DNO-Content-resp-codes-error-handling) this means I don't have access rights to this information. However, when I log in without using API I can access this information, so that seems strange to me. I've also tried logging in with the account with the highest freedom, but this still returns only null information.

Comment: Providing code you have been trying will make it very simple.

Comment: Thanks, I added two example requests.

Comment: HTTP 200 tells you the request was handled okay. What do you mean with 'no data' exactly?

Comment: How many digits does the `CURRENT_DIVISION` variable have?

Comment: It returns a file that I parse with xml.etree.cElementTree. However, all the values (amount of hours worked, date, cost, name of worker etc) are set to Null or 0. This is not a mistake from the xml parser as the raw script does not contain any values either.

According to the exact support this means I don't have access rights but that doesn't make sense as I can see the information when I manually log in.

Comment: CURRENT_DIVISION has 6 digits, I'm pretty sure that's correct as it does allow me to retrieve a lot of other data.

Comment: As a suggestion, you can try to use a free tool from our company ([Invantive Query Tool](http://download.invantive.com/)) to see if the information is actually available and accessible or not. If it works there, the fault is probably on your side.

Comment: In the Query Tool you can do 'set use-log-xml true', dito for REST, to log payload to folder (default is c:\temp) and also check the calls made in 'select * from sessionios@datadictionary'.

Comment: Do you mean like so? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337511/log-all-requests-from-the-python-requests-module

Comment: No. That is in the Invantive Query Tool. It shows you what actions were made and that can help you develop your code.

Answer (score 0):

The exactonline help desk says these four functions only allow you to request your own hours. If you want to request all hours use: /manufactering/TimeTransactions instead. (https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResourcesDetails.aspx?name=ManufacturingTimeTransactions)