# requests return broken pipe, but postman return 500 status

Tags: python, python-requests

when uploading a big file(bigger than server limit). I expect return response with 500 status

1. I tried postman to post API, it return `500` error, that what I need
2. I tried requests to post API

here is requests code:

```
with open('invalid_big_license', 'rb') as f:
    test = s.post(
        url,
        headers=headers,
        data=None,
        files={'file': ('invalid_big_license', f)},
        timeout=1200
    )
```

requests raise

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError(41, 'Protocol wrong type for socket'))
```

what I need is response return with `500` status

if upload file is under server limit(like 1m), requests is success

Comment: can you provide a simpler term, like what you are trying to do, what challenge you have done, what error you are facing and what are your step, so other can replicate

Comment: What's `url`? Does it contain a scheme (`...://`)?

Comment: @deceze `url` is `http://x.x.x.x:port/api/apiname`

Comment: More details are needed, but a number of servers or frameworks (like pyramid with waitress) have a specific size after which they switch to "streaming" the data when receiving large files. It might be that above a certain size your server expects a stream and therefore a different protocol?

Comment: @ChatterOne could say more about this? What should I do?

Comment: Turn on logging for `requests` [as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16337639/606576) and post the output.