# Is it possible to recreate a request from the packets programatically?

Tags: python, fiddler, sniffing

For a script I am making, I need to be able to see the parameters that are sent with a request.
This is possible through Fiddler, but I am trying to automate the process.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tUzZ.jpg) are some screenshots to start with. As you can see in the first picture of Fiddler, I can see the URL of a request and the parameters sent with that request.

I tried to do some packet sniffing with scapy with the code below to see if I can get a similar result, but what I get is in the second picture. Basically, I can get the source and destination of a packet as ip addresses, but the packets themselves are just bytes.

```
def sniffer():
    t = AsyncSniffer(prn = lambda x: x.summary(), count = 10)
    t.start()
    time.sleep(8)
    results = t.results
    print(len(results))
    print(results)
    print(results[0])
```

From my understanding, after we establish a TCP connection, the request is broken down into several IP packets and then sent over to the destination. I would like to be able to replicate the functionality of Fiddler, where I can see the url of the request and then the values of parameters being sent over.

Would it be feasible to recreate the information of a request through only the information gathered from the packets?

Or is this difference because the sniffing is done on Layer 2, and then maybe Fiddler operates on Layer 3/4 before/after the translation into IP packets is done, so it actually sees the content of the original request itself and the result of the combination of packets? If my understanding is wrong, please correct me.

Basically, my question boils down to: "Is there a python module I can use to replicate the features of Fiddler to identify the destination url of a request and the parameters sent along with that request?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sniffed traffic is HTTPS traffic - therefore just by sniffing you won't see any details on the HTTP request/response because it is encrypted via SSL/TLS.

Fiddler is a proxy with HTTPS interception, that is something totally different compared to sniffing traffic on network level. This means that for the client application Fiddler "mimics" the server and for the server Fiddler mimics the client. This allows Fiddler to decrypt the requests/responses and show them to you.

If you want to perform request interception on python level I would recommend to you to use [mitmproxy](https://pypi.org/project/mitmproxy/) instead of Fiddler. This proxy also can perform HTTPS interception but it is written in Python and therefore much easier to integrate in your Python environment.

Alternatively if you just want to see the request/response details of a Python program it may be easier to do so by setting the log-level in an appropriate way. See for example this question: [Log all requests from the python-requests module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337511/log-all-requests-from-the-python-requests-module)