# Where has 'verbose' mode gone in Python requests?

Tags: python, debugging, python-requests

Where is the 'verbose' mode of Requests documented ?

In earlier versions of the [Python requests library](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) a 'verbose' mode [was documented](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.6/user/advanced/#verbose-logging).

I can no longer find this functionality in the documentation. There is this approach in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57325050/364088) which relies on using the logging put out by urllib3 (which underlies requests) but it seems very odd that the 'verbose' mode from Requests has just disappeared.

Comment: While it's not verbose mode, you can log the pieces of the request you want to log.  An answer on how to do this can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658572/python-requests-print-entire-http-request-raw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was removed. From the release history:

> ### [1.0.0 (2012-12-17)](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/community/updates/#id73)
>
> ...
>
> - Removal of all configuration
> - Standard library logging