# Celery: Some tasks are not printing logs on ECS deployment

Tags: celery, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-fargate

I have the following celery setup in production

- Using RabbitMQ as the broker
- I am running multiple instances of the celery using ECS Fargate
- Logs are sent to CloudWatch using default awslogs driver
- Result backend - MongoDB

The issue I am facing is this. A lot of my tasks are not showing logs on cloudwatch.

I just see this log

```
Task task_name[3d56f396-4530-4471-b37c-9ad2985621dd] received
```

But I do not see the actual logs for the execution of this task. Nor do I see the logs for completion - for example something like this is nowhere in the logs to be found

```
Task task_name[3d56f396-4530-4471-b37c-9ad2985621dd] succeeded
```

This does not happen all the time. It happens intermittently but consistently. I see that a lot of tasks are printing the logs.

I can see that result backend has the task results and I know that the task has executed but the logs for the task are completely missing. It is not specific to some `task_name`.

On my local setup, I have not been able to isolate the issue

I am not sure if this is a celery logging issue or awslogs issue. What can I do to troubleshoot this?

** UPDATE **

Found the root cause - it was that I had some code in the codebase that was removing handlers from the root logger. Leaving this question on stack overflow in case someone else faces this issue

[Log all requests from the python-requests module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337511/log-all-requests-from-the-python-requests-module)

Comment: Could it be something as simple as container got removed before the logs were sent to the CloudWatch?

Comment: The containers are alive and I can see that there are more successful logs for tasks in the container after this event

Comment: I was merely thinking about the case when container gets terminated.

Comment: I am so out of ideas - I may even setup kibana just to check if this is an aws issue or the celery task issue.

Comment: @DejanLekic I finally found the root cause - 

It was not anything to do with celery. What was going on was that I had a http debugger as per this thread and once it executed, handlers from root logger got removed. I copied the debug statement from this thread

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337511/log-all-requests-from-the-python-requests-module

Turns out its dangerous to copy the code from stackoverflow :D