# Python request.get() is not following redirects

Tags: python, python-requests, spotify, python-webbrowser

I am trying to use the spotify api which uses OAuth. Once you have been authorized, accessing the authorization url redirects you to your specified redirect_uri with a code in the URL parameters. When I access the authorization url using

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open(authorization_url)
```

it redirects me to my specified redirect uri and I can see the code in the URL on my browser. However, when I read the URL from the requests.get(), as in:

```
import requests
r = requests.get(authorization_url, allow_redirects = True)
print(r.url)
```

Then r.url holds the original authorization_url, and not the redirect uri with the code.

I tried investigating further by looking into the request history with:

```
import requests
r = requests.get(authorization_url, allow_redirects = True)
print(r.history)
for resp in r.history:
    print(r.url)
```

And r.history is a list with only one item [<Response [303]>], which is strange because I've read that 303 means that there was in fact a redirection. But printing r.url from that item in the for loop only gives me the original authorization_url again.

Comment: If there is a difference between your browser and Python code, the difference could be cookies/session already being stored in your browser. Try with incognito mode. As for the history... browser could have HSTS stored headers, while reqeusts redirects to the same page, but `https` version, as opposed to the original `http`.

Comment: You might turn on debug logging as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337511/log-all-requests-from-the-python-requests-module to see what you're getting.  If the 303 doesn't include a `Location:` header, it won't be handled.

Comment: @MartinC. Would this mean that instead of doing requests.get() I should do put or post? Sorry, I understand the different codes now but not really sure how to apply it. I've tried those and requests.head() as well but the same thing happens.

Comment: there are 3 types of redirection. 1. `HTTP` (special code in header) , 2. `HTML` (`<meta content="...">`), 3. `JavaScript` (ie. `document.location = ...`) . `requests` can redirect only for first type.

Comment: @ŠimonKocúrek I think you might be correct. When I deleted the cookies from my browser, the authorization_url takes me to the spotify login page. So I imagine requests.get() has no cookies and is therefore unable to log in automatically.

Comment: if you have to work with `cookies` then you may need `requests.Session()` to get `cookies` from one `request` and use them automatically in another `request`