# How to Set a Custom Logger for the Requests Library in Python?

Tags: python, logging, python-requests

I am trying to set a custom logger for the requests library in Python, but I am having trouble finding the correct way to do it. I have already created a custom logger and configured it with my desired settings, such as the log level, format, and file handler.

no matter what i try the requests library defaults to the default logger and there is no way of setting the logger function :

this is my custom logger but i don't think it's the issue :

```
logger = logging.getLogger('logger')
handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(
    filename=os.path.join(log_dir, 'logger.log'),
    when='D',
    interval=7,
    backupCount=7,
    encoding='utf-8'
)
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s | %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.propagate = False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `requests` is built on top of [`urllib3`](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3). You could simply add your handler to the `urllib3` logger instance:

```py
import requests
import logging, logging.handlers

from pathlib import Path

download_directory = r"c:\temp"
log_directory = r"c:\temp"

urllib3_logger = logging.getLogger("urllib3")
urllib3_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(
    filename=Path(log_directory) / "logger.log",
    when="D",
    interval=7,
    backupCount=7,
    encoding="utf-8"
)

handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s | %(message)s"))

urllib3_logger.addHandler(handler)
```

```py
response = requests.get("https://geomo.ch/portfolio/pdf/digby-webversion-front.jpg")

if response.status_code == 200:
    with (Path(download_directory) / "digby.jpg").open("wb") as file:
        file.write(response.content)
```

---

If you need more detailed log information, you need to use the [`http`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.html) package (see Martijn Pieters' and Yohann's SO answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16337639/42659) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24588289/42659) for a similar question).

They are using [`http.client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPResponse.debuglevel) to log additional information to the console and mask `http.client.print` (not documented; inofficial?) to redirect the logging information to the logger (instead of having the information printed to the console).

Following an derivative example from their answers:

```py
import requests
import logging, logging.handlers

import http.client

from pathlib import Path

download_directory = r"c:\temp"
log_directory = r"c:\temp"

urllib3_logger = logging.getLogger("urllib3")
urllib3_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(
    filename=Path(log_directory) / "logger.log",
    when="D",
    interval=7,
    backupCount=7,
    encoding="utf-8"
)

http.client.print = lambda *args: urllib3_logger.debug(" ".join(args))
http.client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s | %(message)s"))

urllib3_logger.addHandler(handler)
```

```py
response = requests.get("https://geomo.ch/portfolio/pdf/digby-webversion-front.jpg")

if response.status_code == 200:
    with (Path(download_directory) / "digby.jpg").open("wb") as file:
        file.write(response.content)
```

I kept the example simple by choice. I think it's worth to look into Martijn Pieters' and Yohann's SO answers and write a reusable solution.

---

And if you need your custom logger, you just add the handler to both loggers:

```py
import requests
import logging, logging.handlers

import http.client

from pathlib import Path

download_directory = r"c:\temp"
log_directory = r"c:\temp"

urllib3_logger = logging.getLogger("urllib3")
urllib3_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(
    filename=Path(log_directory) / "logger.log",
    when="D",
    interval=7,
    backupCount=7,
    encoding="utf-8"
)

http.client.print = lambda *args: urllib3_logger.debug(" ".join(args))
http.client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s | %(message)s"))

urllib3_logger.addHandler(handler)
```

```py
custom_logger = logging.getLogger("custom_logger")
custom_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

custom_logger.addHandler(handler)
```

```py
response = requests.get("https://geomo.ch/portfolio/pdf/digby-webversion-front.jpg")

if response.status_code == 200:

    custom_logger.info("Download completed")

    with (Path(download_directory) / "digby.jpg").open("wb") as file:
        file.write(response.content)
        custom_logger.info("Image saved")
```

Output:

```
2024-02-26 18:47:29,785 | DEBUG | Starting new HTTPS connection (1): geomo.ch:443
2024-02-26 18:47:30,130 | DEBUG | send: b'GET /portfolio/pdf/...'
2024-02-26 18:47:30,231 | DEBUG | reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
2024-02-26 18:47:30,232 | DEBUG | header: Date: Mon, 26 Feb 2024 22:47:28 GMT
2024-02-26 18:47:30,232 | DEBUG | header: Server: Apache
2024-02-26 18:47:30,232 | DEBUG | header: Upgrade: h2,h2c
2024-02-26 18:47:30,232 | DEBUG | header: Connection: Upgrade, Keep-Alive
2024-02-26 18:47:30,232 | DEBUG | header: Last-Modified: Fri, 25 Jun 2021 ...
2024-02-26 18:47:30,232 | DEBUG | header: ETag: "32786a-5c59aa28aa829"
2024-02-26 18:47:30,232 | DEBUG | header: Accept-Ranges: bytes
2024-02-26 18:47:30,232 | DEBUG | header: Content-Length: 3307626
2024-02-26 18:47:30,232 | DEBUG | header: Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
2024-02-26 18:47:30,232 | DEBUG | header: Content-Type: image/jpeg
2024-02-26 18:47:30,232 | DEBUG | https://geomo.ch:443 "GET /portfolio/..." ...
2024-02-26 18:47:34,722 | INFO | Download completed
2024-02-26 18:47:34,724 | INFO | Image saved
```

---

You could theoretically also redirect `urllib3_logger`'s log records using a custom `logging.Handler`. Here is an outlined example:

```py
class RedirectToAnotherLoggerHandler(logging.Handler):

    def __init__(self, target_logger: logging.Logger):
        super().__init__()
        self.target_logger = target_logger
        self.setLevel(target_logger.level)

    def emit(self, record: logging.LogRecord):
        self.target_logger.handle(record)

custom_logger = logging.getLogger("custom_logger")

redirect_handler = RedirectToAnotherLoggerHandler(custom_logger)

# add your handler
# custom_logger.addHandler(handler)

custom_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

urllib3_logger = logging.getLogger("urllib3")
urllib3_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

urllib3_logger.addHandler(redirect_handler)
```

However, unless you have a very good reason to redirect the logger, I recommend to use the same handler for both loggers rather than writing your own `logging.Handler` redirecting the log records.