# Disable grequests error logs on console

Tags: python, logging, grequests

Is there anyway to disable grequests's logging to console? My applications returns error in the requests part:

```
Timeout: (<requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPConnectionPool object at 0x10daa1a50>, 'Connection to 116.231.213.50 timed out. (connect timeout=5)')
<Greenlet at 0x10d92bf50: <bound method AsyncRequest.send of <grequests.AsyncRequest object at 0x10da97990>>(stream=False)> failed with Timeout
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029717/how-do-i-disable-log-messages-from-the-requests-library) to disable requests's logging but no luck with the grequests.

Comment: Are you sure it's using logging to output those messages? `grequests` doesn't appear to do any logging.

Comment: if you get an error like "time out" or "proxy error", it writes it to console.

Comment: But does it do it using `logging`? How can you tell that it does?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't, the thing is I see the warnings and errors on my console.

Comment: I guess it uses logging as `requests` uses logging, and those warning come from `requests`

Answer (score 1):

If you used the approach in your link to disable `requests` logging (e.g. `logging.getLogger("requests").setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)`) then it should work for `grequests` too. Have you tried it? If you have and it still doesn't behave as you would like, configure logging to show logger names (e.g. via `basicConfig` using `%(name)s` in the format string) and you should see exactly which loggers are producing the messages, and you can then silence them using the same approach as for the `requests` logger.

Comment: I did what you suggested, but still no luck. Now, I am sure that it doesn't use logging. It just prints the error on the console. How can I disable that?

Comment: You know the problem is I can not even catch the exceptions coming from requests like "proxy error" or "timeout error". If I could catch them, I could prevent them from printing on console.