# Python: how to suppress logging statements from third party libraries?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

My logging setting look like

```
import requests
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger('BBProposalGenerator')
```

When I run this, I get logs as

```
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost
INFO:BBProposalGenerator:created proposal: 763099d5-3c8a-47bc-8be8-b71a593c36ac
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost
INFO:BBProposalGenerator:added offer with cubeValueId: f23f801f-7066-49a2-9f1b-1f8c64576a03
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost
INFO:BBProposalGenerator:evaluated proposal: 763099d5-3c8a-47bc-8be8-b71a593c36ac
```

How can I suppress the log statements from `requests` package? so that I only see logs from my code

```
INFO:BBProposalGenerator:created proposal: 763099d5-3c8a-47bc-8be8-b71a593c36ac
INFO:BBProposalGenerator:added offer with cubeValueId: f23f801f-7066-49a2-9f1b-1f8c64576a03
INFO:BBProposalGenerator:evaluated proposal: 763099d5-3c8a-47bc-8be8-b71a593c36ac
```

Comment: `logging.getLogger('requests').setLevel(logging.ERROR)`?

Comment: I got the answer from 


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029717/how-do-i-disable-log-messages-from-the-requests-library

Comment: This is definitely not the same as the listed question. That question pertains to the `requests` module only. The title, which brought me here, refers to *all* 3rd-party libraries. [@VinaySajip's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21945847/1107226) solved that issue for me.

Answer (score 20):

You called `basicConfig()` with a level of `logging.INFO`, which sets the effective level to `INFO` for the root logger, and all descendant loggers which don't have explicitly set levels.  This includes the `requests` loggers, and explains why you're getting these results.

Instead, you can do

```
logging.basicConfig()
```

which will leave the level at its default value of `WARNING`, but add a handler which outputs log messages to the console. Then, set the level on your logger to `INFO`:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('BBProposalGenerator')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Now, `INFO` and higher severity events logged to logger `BBProposalGenerator` or any of its descendants will be printed, but the root logger (and other descendants of it, such as `requests.XXX`) will remain at `WARNING` level and only show `WARNING` or higher messages.

Of course, you can specify a higher level in the `basicConfig()` call - if you specified `ERROR`, for example, you would only see `ERROR` or higher from all the other loggers, but `INFO` or higher from `BBProposalGenerator` and its descendants.

Comment: What if I want to share the logger across modules?

Comment: @Tengerye Loggers are singletons, so you don't need to pass them between modules. Just call `logging.getLogger(<NAME>)` and for a given name you'll always get the same logger object.

Comment: Probably the only answer I've searched that actually explains the reasoning on what's happening under the hood rather than just replying with  _how_ to achieve what's being asked.

Answer (score 6):

what you want to do is apply a filter to all of the loggers so that you can control what is emitted. The only way I could find to apply of filter to all of the loggers is by initializing the logging Logger class with something derived from logging.Logger and applying the filter there. As so:

```
class MyFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        if record.name != 'BBProposalGenerator':
            return False
        return True

class MyLogger(logging.Logger):
    def __init__(self, name):
        logging.Logger.__init__(self, name)
        self.addFilter(MyFilter())
```

And then all you have to do is, the before any loggers are instantiated set the default logger class as your derived class, as so:

```
logging.setLoggerClass(MyLogger)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is not necessary - see my answer.