# How can I completely remove any logging from requests module in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, python-requests

How can I completely remove any logging from requests module in Python? I don't need to set even CRITICAL level. Smth like this

```
import logging
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

but without any messages, even CRITICAL.

Comment: The `requests` module *doesn't log messages*. The embedded `urllib3` library does, but doesn't log any `CRITICAL` level messages. Your code *more than suffices*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable log messages from the Requests library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029717/how-do-i-disable-log-messages-from-the-requests-library)

Comment: This is amazing. Ive added code that goes over every logger in system and sets its level to critical. And ive put this code to the top of every file in my app.
Still i can see messages about my requests.
IMHO its a bug in requests. I mean it makes my program logs unreadable. 9 lines of logs for each request.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all, `requests` *doesn't log anything*; only the `urllib3` library that `requests` depends on does. That library only logs messages at `INFO` and `DEBUG` levels, so setting the log level to `logging.CRITICAL` *disables all messages already*:

```
urllib3_log = logging.getLogger("urllib3")
urllib3_log.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

You could also just disable propagation:

```
logging.getLogger("urllib3").propagate = False
```

That's enough to completely disable all logging that the `urllib3` library does.

The `urllib3` project has installed a [`NullHandler()`](https://docs.python.org/library/logging.handlers.html#nullhandler) handler object on the project root logger, which ensures that the [`lastResort` handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.lastResort) is not used for unhandled messages, even when propagation has been disabled.

That said, if you don't trust that future versions of `requests` won't use `sys.maxint` as a log level, and at the same time neglect to set a `NullHandler()`, then by all means add your own `NullHandler()` on the project root logger object, and then disable propagation there:

```
import logging

requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests")
requests_log.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
requests_log.propagate = False
```

Now all logging within the `requests` hierarchy will be directed to the `NullHandler()` instance, and with `propagate` set to `False` logging stops there. You can use this to silence any logger in the hierarchy.

In my opinion, that's overkill, no `requests` release made so far uses logging, and the project is staffed with capable developers that are unlikely to misconfigure the logging setup if they ever did add logging.

Comment: I'm on python version 2.7.6 (requests 2.12.4, urllib3 1.7.1). Even after I do all these I get log entry per request. There's no indication where these logs are from though.

Comment: @chanux: I'm sorry, why are you telling me your versions?

Comment: Sorry I pressed enter accidentally :). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @chanux: I updated the answer to be more clear that you'd need to disable logging for `urllib3`, not `requests`.

Comment: What is the purpose of the line `requests_log.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())`? The _[Logging HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#library-config)_ recommends to attach a `logging.NullHandler` to the top-level logger of your _library_, and only if you don't want your library's users to get your library's event messages of severity `logging.WARNING` or greater printed to `sys.stderr` in the absence of a logging configuration in their application. But here this is not the library code, this is the application code. So no need to redirect anything since `propagate` is `False`.

Comment: @Maggyero: the point is that `requests` doesn't attach a `NullHandler` to its root logger (there isn't even a root logger). Placing a `NullHandler` there is only needed if you as an application developer don't trust a future version of `requests` to add logging and not take care of putting a `NullHandler` in place for you.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification: after looking again at the source code of the [logging.Logger.callHandlers](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1575) method, I realized that `logging.getLogger("requests").propagate = False` is not enough to prevent the fallback to the [`logggin.lastResort`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#what-happens-if-no-configuration-is-provided) handler. So `logging.getLogger("requests").addHandler(logging.NullHandler)` is necessary, _but only if the application code doesn't define its own loggers._ Can I add this to your answer?

Comment: @Maggyero: I've expanded on the role of `NullHandler`, propagation and `lastResort` a little.

Comment: @Maggyero: your edit shows you may be misunderstanding my answer entirely. I definitely meant to target `requests`, **not** `urllib3`, which already does the right thing as a library.

Comment: My bad, the main point of my edit (besides formatting improvement) was to precise that adding a `logging.NullHandler()` to the library logger is necessary only if the application has not attached a handler to the `logging.RootLogger`, since I thought in this case there would be no fallback to the `logging.lastResort` handler, as the `found` variable in `logging.Logger.callHandlers` would not be `0`. But this is incorrect: `propagate = False` breaks the `while` loop, so the `found` variable does not get incremented by the handler attached to the `logging.RootLogger` parent logger, so it is `0`.

Comment: But something is still confusing for the reader. You say: "The `urllib3` project has installed a `NullHandler()` handler". Then later you say: "That said, if you don't trust that future versions of `requests` won't use `sys.maxint` as a log level, and at the same time neglect to set a `NullHandler()`"? In the 2nd sentence about `requests`, it looks like you are referring to the first sentence about `urllib3`, which is confusing. And to me you cannot trust any libraries, so the application code should add a `NullHandler()` to `urllib3` too, to be safe (even if `urllib3` _currently_ has one).

Comment: @Maggyero: no, I start with stating that `requests` doesn't log anything, only the `urllib3` library. `requests` calls call `urllib3` code, which log stuff. The OP silenced the `requests` library, but not `urllib3`. Now, a future update of `requests` could add logging itself, but forget to add a nullhandler (unlikely, but possible), then log using `sys.maxint` as the log level (far less likely still).

Comment: General question: Within the package, how does adding null handler to child logger (__name__) prevent the root logger from displaying log messages (lastResort)? The log will still propagate to the root logger isnt it? There is always a root logger isn't it?

Comment: @variable: That's not how propagation works, actually. The `Logger` class has a [`callHandlers` method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2f8d4f08e2fa62cd5c3f6f824be3e7513ff87e07/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1633-L1661); this method doesn't recurse nor is it called on each logger object in the hierarchy. It is called *once*, on the logger object that you sent the log message to, and simply loops over the `.parent` chain to test each logger down to the root. This method will call `lastResort`, but *only if no handlers are found anywhere*.

Comment: @variable: put differently: the root logger not having a handler doesn't mean it'll use `lastResort`, `lastResort` is really only used as a last resort when *nothing else* handled a log message, anywhere.

Comment: My confusion is cleared when I realised that the root logger when running the library is different to the root logger when the library is imported.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer didn't work out for me. But [urllib3 docs](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#tls-warnings) point out that you can disable the logging with this:

```
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()
```

Source: [urllib3 docs](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#tls-warnings)

Comment: This is a cleaner solution. However, I tend to use `requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()` when importing strictly `requests` even though it may produce a `Module Not Found` in your IDE