# Django: Disable python Requests Library Logging

Tags: python, django, logging, python-requests

I'm trying to remove logging from requests library. I tried everything on the web but I keep getting spam like this:

```
send: 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.3.0 CPython/2.7.10 Darwin/15.2.0\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found\r\n'
header: Cache-Control: private
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
header: Location: https://www.google.pt/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=plwnV9OUHYas8wekio2ADw
header: Content-Length: 259
header: Date: Mon, 02 May 2016 13:56:54 GMT
send: 'GET /?gfe_rd=cr&ei=plwnV9OUHYas8wekio2ADw HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.pt\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.3.0 CPython/2.7.10 Darwin/15.2.0\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Date: Mon, 02 May 2016 13:56:54 GMT
header: Expires: -1
header: Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
header: P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See https://www.google.com/support/accounts/answer/151657?hl=en for more info."
header: Content-Encoding: gzip
header: Server: gws
header: X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
header: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
header: Set-Cookie: NID=79=OojMOTKzHw7ADN02S4j_nk-sRaWCeQ8P-JTKiCEarWlwIqzYnH2tP0GEVOov-Svl8Pn5-cMpv6sILvEKUaC0PayZe8PeAzN8uaqpTeDjJpka2KDjZyOSXig7bQBqw-mv; expires=Tue, 01-Nov-2016 13:56:54 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.pt; HttpOnly
header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

And all of this is just for this line of code: `requests.get('https://www.google.com', timeout=5)`

My current settings is like this:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'null': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.NullHandler',
        },
        'console': {
            # logging handler that outputs log messages to terminal
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'level': 'WARNING', # message level to be written to console
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django.db': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
        },
        'boto': {
            'level': 'CRITICAL',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'requests.packages.urllib3': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to remove this spam? I am getting this logging whenever I use boto s3 or the requests library. I already trying removing it with this settings, and with logging.disable(...) and logging.getLogger("urllib3").setLevel(logging.WARNING)

Comment: Have a look at the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24344045/how-can-i-completely-remove-any-logging-from-requests-module-in-python)

Comment: This wont help at least in the version I'm using: requests==2.3.0.
If you debug it you'll find somewhere in their code "if this.debuglevel>0: print (...)" => it means its hardcoded for debuglevel > 0 and it's a print not a logger. I found somewhere it was a bug and might be fixed in newer versions

Answer (score 1):

For those who want to ignore this same span adding the following line to the beginning of your file works just fine (not the best solution though):

```
httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 0
```