# Stop Log from Outputting in py2neo

Tags: logging, neo4j, py2neo

How can I stop py2neo from spitting out each created relationship/node, like the following:

> (http://localhost:7474/db/data/'
>   ref=u'relationship/13441' start=u'node/13446' end=u'node/3' type=u'IN'
>   properties={}>,)

As encouraged by [this page](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-configuration.html#_server_logging_configuration), when I set the below line to OFF

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=OFF
```

I silence logging when I call a function which creates the relationship/node. However, if I directly create something (graph.create(...) in my main, then I still see this print to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about running `Graph.create` from a Python console then the value you see is the return value from the method, not a log entry.

Note also that the logging setting you refer to is for the server, not the driver.

Comment: how can i set logging for driver

Answer (score 6):

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11029841) answer to another question and was successful in suppressing the log messages

```
logging.getLogger("py2neo.batch").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logging.getLogger("py2neo.cypher").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

http://py2neo.org/v3/database.html?highlight=relation

```
logging.getLogger("neo4j").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logging.getLogger("httpstream").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Answer (score 0):

this work for me!

```
logging.getLogger("py2neo").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```