# How to add a logger to a module in Python?

Tags: python, logging

I am discovering `logging` and I would like to integrate it inside a class for external usage. It means, the user can either choose to ignore the logging feature or bind an handler to it.

I currently have this in my test module:

```
import logging
class Test:
   def __init__(self):
      self.logger = logging.getlogger(__module__ + '.Test')

   def hello(self):
      self.logger.warn('Hello World!')


test = Test()
test.hello()
```

With this I get the error

```
No handlers could be found for logger
```

I precisely don't want to bind a handler to this logger otherwise I may override the choice of the parent. I thought the default handler was `Nullhandler`.

What would be the correct pattern to integrate a logging feature inside an independant module?

Of course one solution would be to check if no handlers are binded to it:

```
if not len(self.logger): l.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
```

Comment: This can't possibly be the real code. `Test` has no attribute `warn`. `self.warn('Hello World!')` would fail.

Comment: @PeterWood my mistake :(

Comment: I created a wrapper module for the logging module that provides my own getLogger function that checks "if not logger.handlers" and adds a console handler. So your suggested solution should work.

Comment: @DavidCullen It should yes, but I am wondering if this is the proper solution. Adding logging capabilities to Python modules should be a very common need which would correspond to a well known design pattern. I am actually looking for it

Comment: This question shows what happens when module writers add logging to their modules: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029717/how-do-i-disable-log-messages-from-the-requests-library. People immediately start looking for ways to turn off the logging. So it might not be as common as you think.

Comment: Interesting. This would advise me to disable the logger by default which is not a bad idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use in one of my projects.

```
def get_logger(log_level,log_name='YourNameGoesHere'):
    logger = logging.getLogger(log_name)
    if not logger.handlers:
        logger.setLevel(log_level)
        ch = logging.StreamHandler()
        ch.setLevel(log_level)
        ch.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
            '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
        ))
        logger.addHandler(ch)
        logger.propagate = 0
    return logger
```