# Schedule package: Suppress "Running job Every" messages

Tags: python, logging, schedule

I'm using 'schedule' for a current project:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schedule

It's great, but I want to suppress the "Running job Every x seconds" log message that gets triggered every time a scheduled task is run. Example of what I mean below:

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this? Below is my current logging.basicConfig, I'm quite new to configuring logging beyond the absolute basics, so the solution may lie more with that:

```
# Define overall logging settings; these log levels/format go to file
logging.basicConfig(level=variables.settings['log_level_file'],
                    format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                    filename='logs\log.log')

# Set up Handlers and Formatters; these log levels/format go to console
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(variables.settings['log_level_console'])
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
console.setFormatter(formatter)
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)
```

Comment: The github repo has this [issue](https://github.com/dbader/schedule/issues/30). Also, there is a [pull request](https://github.com/dbader/schedule/pull/76) with the quiet job option.

Comment: Also, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029717/how-do-i-disable-log-messages-from-the-requests-library). You want to set the `'schedule'` logger's level to `logging.DEBUG`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks @Meloman, that did the job perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Meloman pointed out, you can directly set the individual 'schedule' logger to a higher level than the INFO default:

```
logging.getLogger('schedule').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```