# Don't Log 'Certificate did not match expected hostname' Error Messages

Tags: python, request, ssl-certificate

My web app requests several URLs and sometimes SSL certificate errors are raised. They are all third party URLs so I can't fix their errors and I prefer not to log them. Nevertheless, something is logging this by itself: `2017-08-05 00:22:49,496 ERROR -- : Certificate did not match expected hostname: www.improving-autonomy.org. Certificate: {'subjectAltName': [('DNS', '*.wordpress.com'), ('DNS', 'wordpress.com')], 'subject': ((('commonName', u'*.wordpress.com'),),)}` Anyone knows how can I stop it? Please find my code bellow. Many thanks in advance!

```
try :
    ua = UserAgent()
    headers = {'Content-Type' : 'text/html', 'Accept-Encoding' : None, 'User-Agent' : ua.random}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=10)
except ssl.CertificateError as e :
    pass
```

**UPDATED -- :**
It looks like requests module logs it (connection.py). Why it keeps logging if I'm already catching the same exception?

```
def _match_hostname(cert, asserted_hostname):
    try:
        match_hostname(cert, asserted_hostname)
    except CertificateError as e:
        log.error(
            'Certificate did not match expected hostname: %s. '
            'Certificate: %s', asserted_hostname, cert
        )
    # Add cert to exception and reraise so client code can inspect
    # the cert when catching the exception, if they want to
    e._peer_cert = cert
    raise
```

Comment: Did you try tracing through a debugger to see where that logging is actually happening? It looks like maybe there is a check for an error, error is found, a log is made, and then an exception is raised. Needs to be verified through tracing the code though.

Comment: It's happening in the requests module. connection.py file

Comment: Any idea? I am already catching the same exception. Why is it logging by itself anyway?

Comment: Did you find the piece of code that is actually logging that line to see what the logic is around that?

Comment: Just  updated my question with the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. You *are* catching the same exception, but what you are not seeing is *where* this is happening. Let's take a look at the snippet of what is happening here:

```
except CertificateError as e:
    log.error(
        'Certificate did not match expected hostname: %s. '
        'Certificate: %s', asserted_hostname, cert
    )
# Add cert to exception and reraise so client code can inspect
# the cert when catching the exception, if they want to
e._peer_cert = cert
raise
```

So, when the exception is first raised, that code catches the `CertificateError`, then it makes a `log.error`, assigns the cert as an attribute, per the comment in the code, then, a call to `raise` is made.

That empty `raise` call is now going to *re-raise* the last exception made, which *is* the `CertificateError` exception, and *that* is what you are catching. So the log call has already been made by that code, and your exception catching is being made from that specific *raise* call.

Comment: I see... And there's anyway to avoid this first log?

Comment: You can play around with the log level for those modules I believe. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029717/how-do-i-disable-log-messages-from-the-requests-library) answer for some information on this to see if it helps you.

Comment: I write here the working code: `logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3").setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)`

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the exception and then print it's type:

```
except Exception as exc:
    print exc, exc.message, exc.__class__
```

Then use this specific exception type in your code, which should work. Also you can add an `else` clause after the except statement, and put the logging code there. This code will be executed only if the try block executed successfully

Comment: request module logs it catching a `CertificateError`