# Stop submodules logging - running script from batch file

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file, logging

I have a python script with a cli argument parser (based on argparse)
I am calling it from a batch file:

```bat
set VAR1=arg_1
set VAR2=arg_2

python script.py --arg1 %VAR1% --arg2 %VAR2%
```

within the `script.py` I call a logger:

```python
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

- This script utilizes chromedriver, selenium and requests to automate some clicking and moving between web pages.
- When running from within `PyCharm` (configured so that the script has `arg_1` and `arg_2` passed to it) everything is great - I get log messages from my logger only.
- When I run the batch file - I get a bunch of logging messages from chromedriver or requests (I think).

**I have tried:**

- `@echo off` at the start of the batch file.
- Setting the level on the root logger.
- Getting the logging logger dictionary and setting each logger to WARNING - based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029717/how-do-i-disable-log-messages-from-the-requests-library).

None of these work and I keep getting logging messages from submodules - ONLY when run from a batch file.

Anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following configuration options to do this

```
import logging.config
logging.config.dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
})
```

Comment: This did not work. I think the logs are coming from chromedriver (or chrome itself) because I only see it when run from command line. From PyCharm I don't see these logs...

Comment: Are you setting the logs inside 
    if __name__ == "__main__" ? 

If yes, move the logging config outside that. If not, please add the extra logs in your question that you want to remove to get a clear idea of where the logs might be coming from.