# Is it possible to suppress the output of the sh module?

Tags: python

When using the python sh module, there are outputs from the module itself, like the status of command it is running, etc.  Is it possible to suppress that?  I am *not* referring to the output of the command being executed, but what the module prints when it executes.

For example, if the script contains:

```
import pip
pip.main(['install', "sh"])

import sh

cmdArgs = ["-lrt","/tmp"]
sh.ls(cmdArgs)
```

When the script is run, the following is output:

```
<Command '/bin/ls -lrt /tmp'>: starting process
<Command '/bin/ls -lrt /tmp', pid 22235>: process started
<Command '/bin/ls -lrt /tmp', pid 22235>: process completed
```

I would prefer no output.  I was unable to find anything in http://amoffat.github.io/sh/

Comment: It must be possible since I don't see that when I run your script. I don't know why though.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, my script was rather large, so I only added an 'untested' snippet.  The script does a pip install of sh at the beginning.  I've modified the above to do that.  IF I comment that out (since sh was installed on first run), it does not log.  If I leave it in, it prints the log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As can be seen from https://github.com/amoffat/sh/blob/master/sh.py#L754 <sub>(found by searching the sources for `<Command`, then looking through the references to the function that produces that string)</sub> , these are `logging` messages with `INFO` level, so they will appear if you are using `logging`.

As such, they can be silenced using the standard `logging` machinery as per [How do I disable log messages from the Requests library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029717/how-do-i-disable-log-messages-from-the-requests-library):

```
# sh uses a wrapper over logging.Logger, its logger names are "sh.<smth>"
# see sh.Logger.__init__ : https://github.com/amoffat/sh/blob/master/sh.py#L608
logging.getLogger("sh").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```