# OpenAPI/Swagger - How to specify different logging level for only certain APIs

Tags: python, logging, swagger, openapi

I have been recently working on a project using OAS 3.0 with swagger editor and codegen to generate my **Python** back-end server code. And it's been a while since I was trying to find an answer for this. My openapi definition is in yaml and it specifies couple of GET and POST APIs. What I see now is that auto-generated code is logging messages by itself when the outside hits the API endpoints, like with status 200, 404, etc.

After a while of investigation, I found the messages are logged by the logger "werkzeug" at the level of "INFO". I also found the way to set the level higher, like WARNING or ERROR. However if I'm doing so, I will pretty much lose every logging messages. What I want to do is only do loggings for certain APIs (not for all) on certain level, not logging everything on the same level for every API specified in the OpenAPI.

Is there anyway to do so with OpenAPI/Swagger instead of hacking into connecxion/flaskapi libraries? Appreciate your time reading this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029717/how-do-i-disable-log-messages-from-the-requests-library Does this help? You might be able to do `logging.getLogger('werkzeug').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)` to only show critical errors, which you probably do want to see. If you really want to disable all logging entirely, you can use `setLevel(100)`, that should work for pretty much all libraries.