# Set log level for a particular requests.Session

Tags: python, python-requests

I can set the log level for everything coming from the requests package in the usual fashion:

`logging.getLogger('requests').setLevel(...)`

But I have a `requests.Session` which is especially chatty, and I want to set the log level separately for requests originating from that session. The following code sample shows what I'd like to do (the line marked XX).

```
import requests
import logging

requests.get('https://example.com/').close()
# log output:
# 2020-04-13 19:01:44 [DEBUG] Starting new HTTPS connection (1): example.com:443
# 2020-04-13 19:01:44 [DEBUG] https://example.com:443 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 648


s = requests.Session()
s.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO) # XX this doesn't exist, but illustrates what I want to do
s.get('https://example.com/').close() # nothing should be logged
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disable log messages from the Requests library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029717/how-do-i-disable-log-messages-from-the-requests-library)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36208664). Maybe getting a list of all existing loggers helps.

Comment: @mkrieger1 it clearly does not answer my question: in the first line of my post I make it clear that I know how to disable logging for requests. I just want to disable it for a particular session.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do that with sessions. Maybe if you add a [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#filter-objects) you avoid logging the requests you don't want?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a decorator for `requests` and `urllib3` (used by requests) in order to optionally provide you a desired logging level just for specific functions.

This would look like this:

```py
import logging
import requests
import functools

logging.basicConfig()

requests_logger = logging.getLogger("requests")
requests_logger_level = requests_logger.getEffectiveLevel()
urllib3_logger = logging.getLogger("urllib3")
urllib3_logger_level = requests_logger.getEffectiveLevel()

url = 'https://pypi.org/pypi/requests/json'


def requests_debug(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def func(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            requests_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
            urllib3_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            requests_logger.setLevel(requests_logger_level)
            urllib3_logger.setLevel(urllib3_logger_level)
    return func


@requests_debug
def get_data():
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.json()['info']['author']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = get_data()
    print(a)
```

Comment: this approach is problematic because it's not threadsafe; other threads using requests at the same time that a call to get_data is happening may or may not show their log messages.