# Unable to disable logging from python's request library

Tags: python, logging, python-requests

I'm trying to remove logging from the requests library and I've already read and tried the other answers on stack overflow, but they don't seem to work.

I'm parsing a webpage for urls in the html code and then downloading zip files from each of the urls. After downloading all the zip files, I get a message from the requests libraries:

Downloading data from:

```
http://viewfinderpanoramas.org/Coverage%20map%20viewfinderpanoramas_org3.htm
```

Here's my code. I'm importing the class and running the `download_data` method from another file.

```
import os
import argparse
import requests
import re
import logging
from tqdm import tqdm

"""
Downloads all zip files from the viewfinder panoramas elevation dataset
"""

class ElevationScraper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data_url = "http://viewfinderpanoramas.org/Coverage%20map%20viewfinderpanoramas_org3.htm"
        self.base_dir = "./data/elevation/"
        self.elevation_dir = os.path.join(self.base_dir, "elevation")
        logging.getLogger("requests").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
        logging.getLogger("requests").propagate = True

        
    def download_data(self):
        # get html from self.data_url and get all urls in the html code
        req = requests.get(self.data_url)
        urls = re.findall(r"\"(https?://\S+)\"", str(req.text))

        # first four are irrelevant links so remove those
        urls = urls[4:]
        with open(os.path.join(self.base_dir, "urls.txt"), "w") as url_file:
            for url in urls:
                url_file.write(url + "\n")
        
        # downloading all zip files
        if not os.path.exists(self.elevation_dir):
            os.mkdir(self.elevation_dir)

        print("Downloading " + str(len(urls)) + " data files to " + self.elevation_dir + " from " + self.data_url)
        
        for url in tqdm(urls[:3]):
            filename = url.split("/")[-1]

            with open(os.path.join(self.base_dir, "elevation", filename), "wb") as data_file:
                req = requests.get(url)
                data_file.write(req.content)
```

Output:

```
shrey@Shrey-TPL480 MINGW64 ~/dev/Landslide-Prediction (main)
$ python download_elevation.py
Downloading 1140 data files to ./data/elevation/elevation from http://viewfinderpanoramas.org/Coverage%20map%20viewfinderpanoramas_org3.htm
100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 3/3 [00:08<00:00,  2.75s/it] 
Downloading data from http://viewfinderpanoramas.org/Coverage%20map%20viewfinderpanoramas_org3.htm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `setLevel` to critical like this `logging.getLogger("requests").setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)` or you can use `requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()`. See this: [How do I disable log messages from the Requests library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029717/how-do-i-disable-log-messages-from-the-requests-library). A question like this is alreasy asked.