# Python HTTP requests suddenly verbose

Tags: python, python-requests

My script (created in 2017) requests a couple of URLs (`response = requests.post(initial_url, data = data`) and parses the response content. A few days ago, the script started printing out status information from the `requests` module:

```
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): url:443
url:443 "POST /login?url=https%3A//url HTTP/1.1" 302 202
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): second.url:443
second.url:443 "GET /path HTTP/1.1" 302 None
second.url:443 "GET /login?referer=path HTTP/1.1" 302 None
second.url:443 "GET /path HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```

I did not change anything in my code – why does `requests` act so verbose?

Comment: Looks like something in your code or perhaps in an imported module has set the logging level to a low value.

Comment: Thanks – I found and removed the culprit (pyonepassword).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general answer is that `requests` use the `logging` module internally. As explained in ["How do I disable log messages from the Requests library?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11029841/797845), the log level can be changed:

```
# ...after everything else has been imported
import logging
logging.getLogger("requests").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Answer (score 0):

Justin's comment answered my question.

Comment: Please, share the solution so that it can help others (including myself)

Comment: Module pyonepassword modified the log level for module requests (obviously a bug). I switched to a different 1Password module to solve the problem..