# How to skip the DEBUG logs with in the console using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium with python.
and I'm getting these in the output:
[image]

Which I want to skip.
So please tell me how can I skip these warnings.

Comment: You should post whichs libraries are you using, but check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029717/how-do-i-disable-log-messages-from-the-requests-library

Answer (score 0):

To suppress the *DEBUG* logs you can use `add_experimental_option()` through an instance of `Options()` as follows:

```
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```